# Unify the look of accept and recommend votes

Tags: feature-request, design, accepted-answer, collectives

A recent addition is the "recommended by collective" feature. It appears as a small button below the accept button and when active shows a small message above the answer.

[image]

This is now different from what the accept button looks like. I propose that the accept checkmark is made the same size as the new button and that a similar message is shown above the "recommended by collective" message. E.g.

> Answer recommended by the question asker

Comment: IMHO not with that phrasing. In my interpretation, acceptance never implied any sort of recommendation -- the tooltip says "The question owner accepted this as the best answer", and often even that has to be taken with a grain of salt. I'd even go so far to say that a lot of people clicking it are in no position to be recommending anything regarding the topic of their inquiry.

Comment: @dan it's an example. It could say something else, e.g "answer preferred by..." or "answer like by..."

Comment: As of now, too many people think it means it's best or the correct answer.

Comment: Codidact [handles this way better](https://meta.codidact.com/posts/277957), FWIW.

Comment: I am in favor of making it way smaller. But IMO the acceptance should not be shown at all if there is a recommended by collective active on the answer. The acceptance flag already is noise, paired with this new feature it has become super noise.

Comment: Just a point of clarification. The button under the bounty award indicator only appears for recognized members of a collective (and moderators?). [As you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VduV5.png) ordinary users cannot see that button.

Comment: @ian neither does the accept button